# PostGIS st_intersects with exceptions

Tags: postgis

I have a query in PostGIS using st_intersects like this

```
SELECT "name", "id_punto", "geometry", "properties", "type" FROM "points" AS "points" WHERE st_intersects("geometry",
'POLYGON ((-103.7222993373871 19.24991497165985,-103.71497154235841 19.24991497165985,-103.71497154235841 19.251824273576922,-103.7222993373871 19.251824273576922,-103.7222993373871 19.24991497165985))') = true;
```

Using st_intersects I bring all the points within a polygon that I indicated everything works well and shows a result like this:

[image]

My question is how I can exclude from the result some points within a multipoint for example:

```
MULTIPOINT (-103.7220613692669 19.25003446877862, -103.7211920807273 19.25105574878461)
```

try with a leftjoin but I did not get it

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints.html (Returns a version of the given geometry with duplicated points/multi-points removed)

Comment: note that those *MultiPoints* are not created by that query, but have to be in your source table. do you want to completely remove e.g. all *Multipoints*? or is @Mapperz suggestion spot on?

Answer (score 1):

Since PostGIS 2.3.0 you can use [ST_Within](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html) for a Point-In-Point relationship.

You can add a `AND NOT` condition to the `WHERE` clause to exclude them.

The `WHERE` clause returns the rows for which the condition is true, so you also can establish a `condition = false` instead of the `NOT` operator.

Assuming that the `geometry` column has setted the `SRID=4326`, both queries are possible:

```
SELECT
  p.name,  
  p.id_punto,
  p.geometry,
  p.properties,
  p.type
FROM points AS p 
WHERE
  St_Tntersects(
    p.geometry, 
    'SRID=4326; POLYGON(( -103.7222993373871 19.24991497165985, -103.71497154235841 19.24991497165985, -103.71497154235841 19.251824273576922, -103.7222993373871 19.251824273576922, -103.7222993373871 19.24991497165985))'::geometry
  )
  AND NOT
  ST_Within(
    p.geometry, 
    'SRID=4326; MULTIPOINT( -103.7220613692669 19.25003446877862, -103.7211920807273 19.25105574878461)'::geometry
  )
;
```

or

```
SELECT
  p.name,  
  p.id_punto,
  p.geometry,
  p.properties,
  p.type
FROM points AS p 
WHERE
  St_Tntersects(
    p.geometry, 
    'SRID=4326; POLYGON(( -103.7222993373871 19.24991497165985, -103.71497154235841 19.24991497165985, -103.71497154235841 19.251824273576922, -103.7222993373871 19.251824273576922, -103.7222993373871 19.24991497165985))'::geometry
  )
  AND 
  ST_Within(
    p.geometry, 
    'SRID=4326; MULTIPOINT( -103.7220613692669 19.25003446877862, -103.7211920807273 19.25105574878461)'::geometry
  ) = false
;
```

---

`ST_Within()` applied to point-in-point relationship returns true only when the first point geometry is exactly a part of the multipoint geometry. You can use [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) to exclude them by a distance thereshold.